# Как распарсить полученный токен в Python

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, token

В результате Post-запроса получаю вот такой ответ:
"authToken":"oo8pwbHZGh7YQu-AwcZ4ESg2rozyzBeNA5suNDEfgGZIPmtxtZY9Hk8aeefEpSAmW8vp0jwPfTYyZtH__-1B5w==","expireAt":"2019-22-05 05:44:19"}
Сам токен вот:
oo8pwbHZGh7YQu-AwcZ4ESg2rozyzBeNA5suNDEfgGZIPmtxtZY9Hk8aeefEpSAmW8vp0jwPfTYyZtH__-1B5w==
Как его оттуда вытащить?

Comment: Судя по приведённому куску ответа, это обычный JSON. Тогда это делается крайне легко с помощью функции `json.loads`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по формату это JSON. Вот пример:

```
import json

x =  '{ "authToken":"oo8pwbHZGh7YQu-AwcZ4ESg2rozyzBeNA5suNDEfgGZIPmtxtZY9Hk8aeefEpSAmW8vp0jwPfTYyZtH__-1B5w==","expireAt":"2019-22-05 05:44:19"}}'

# Парсим x:
y = json.loads(x)

# результатом будет тип dictionary:
print(y["authToken"])
```

Comment: Может я не допонял, но мне нужно значение этого ключа достать, а не ключ)

Comment: `print(y["authToken"])` выведет `oo8pwbHZGh7YQu-AwcZ4ESg2rozyzBeNA5suNDEfgGZIPmtxtZY9Hk8aeefEpSAmW8vp0jwPfTYyZtH__-1B5w==`. Что не так? Или в этом токене еще какоето скрытое значение есть и его нужно распарсить?

Comment: Все ок. Спасибо большое. Отмечу как ответ